# Floating div width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to set width (or max-width) value of the floating div.
I have tried various options, but none of them helped me.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id = "basicInfo" class = "tab active">
        <h1>Results</h1>
        <span style="clear: both;"></span>

        <p>Browser version: internet explorer 8</p>
        <h2>Plan details:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Plan description: not set</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id = "statInfo" class = "tab">
        <div id="chartcontainer"><p>Pie chart placeholder</p></div>
        <h1>Statistics</h1>     
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.tab-content {
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background:#FEFEFE;
    min-width: 1165px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#basicInfo {
    border-style: none;
}
#statInfo {
    border-style: none;
}
#chartcontainer {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height:200px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    float:right;
}
.clr {
    clear:both;
}
```

Div with class `chartcointainer` should float to the right, next to the three "text" paragraphs. 
Height is changing correctly, but width is problem. `chartcontainer` always take whole "blank space" from end of paragraphs to the edge of the parent div.

Thanks

Comment: how the output will be?

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javasluud/wLtzvf5t/) In which only the `width` for `.tab-content` has been changed. There it seems to be working fine. (chrome 36 on os x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
right:0; 
position:absolute;
```